# Array data in WHERE clause

Tags: arrays, doctrine, where-clause

Have a problem with array in my where clause. I have an array in my object. YML:

```
Shoe
  ShoeOne
    sizes:
     - 30
     - 31
     - 32
     - 33
   ...
  ShoeTwo
   ...
```

How can I select shoes that matches between two ranges?

Tried to use BETWEEN but array is serialized. Is there function to make some select in serialized array in Doctrine/MySql or better use a string? Or better use what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
 static function makeOrQueryFromArray($array, $table_name)
  {
        $query="(";
        foreach ($array as $value)
        {
          $query .= "s.$table_name LIKE '%i:$value%' OR ";
        }
        return substr($query,0,strlen($query)-4).")";
  }
```

Comment: That'll work, but you won't be able to use an index for that query (because of unanchored `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause), which could cause performance problems as your application scales.  You might want to consider a different mechanism such as Lucene, or create a separate table that maps shoes to their sizes.